# Unable to change hardisk data in virtualbox

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox

Using Windows 10, I have a virtualbox running scientifix linux.
I now need to emulate a "real" harddrive, and as google, forums, and superuser has taught me, this can be achieved as such:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage setextradata "Testinstall" "VBoxInternal/Devices/piix4ide/0/Config/PrimaryMaster/FirmwareRevision" "ISD000081"

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage setextradata "Testinstall" "VBoxInternal/Devices/piix4ide/0/Config/PrimaryMaster/SerialNumber" "83CJ0015"

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage setextradata "Testinstall" "VBoxInternal/Devices/piix4ide/0/Config/PrimaryMaster/ModelNumber" "INTEL SSD1602CW"
```

....which are the commands exactly as entered by me.

However, the output of `hdparm -I /dev/sda` still lists the stock "VBOX HARDDISK" with its associated data.

Things I've tried:

- Doublecheck the disk controller. It's set to PIIX4. I also tried to `setextradata` for piix3, just in case, but the result doesn't change.
- As `vboxmanage` offers very little in terms of verbosity, I decided to bongle up my command, to see if there were any ways of spotting obvious errors:

  - Typing the machine name incorrectly: "TestInstallaoeu". Throws an error, indicating that the machine name I originally typed is correct
  - Mistyping the parameter to change: `"VBoxInternal/Bogus/Parameter" "BogusData"`. This does not produce an error, indicating that there may be a typo in my command (even though I am unable to spot one).
- I've tried both with and without wrapping the commands in doublequotes as above, but it doesn't seem to make a difference, as there aren't any whitespaces anyway.

I'm at a loss how to proceed. Everything I've read indicates that it should work as it is, but my experiences are to the contrary.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Additional data as (partially) requested.

- Virtualbox version: 5.1.4 r110228
- Host OS: Windows 10
- Guest OS: Scientific Linux 6.7 (kernel 2.6.32)

None of the metadatafiles in the virtual machine directory seems to contain the data I've entered. Checked both the `.vbox` file and the `.vbox-prev` file.

The `.vbox` entry for harddisk:

```
  <HardDisks>
    <HardDisk uuid="{808541e0-6629-47cd-96b3-7ff6021d9dcc}" location="TestDisk.vdi" format="VDI" type="Normal"/>
  </HardDisks>
```

The `.vbox` entry for storage controller:

```
<StorageController name="IDE" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true">
        <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" hotpluggable="false" port="1" device="0"/>
        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{808541e0-6629-47cd-96b3-7ff6021d9dcc}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
      </StorageController>
```

One thing I noticed in the file is that there are remnants from the bogus-command I entered:

```
<ExtraDataItem name="VboxInternal/Bogus/Parameter" value="asdf"/>
```

...so at least some of my commands do as intended.

The `.vbox` in its entirety can be seen here: [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/VsR2ivZe)

---

**NB:**
I noticed just now that in an attemt at anonymizing the data I fingerfudged the machine name and disk name in this post and the linked pastebin. When reading any references to "TestDisk" and "Testinstall", keep in mind that these are replacement labels that in actuality are identical names. "Testinstall" and "TestDisk" are therefore interchangable in this case.

---

**Edit 2:**
After trying various combinations, I've now found a set of commands that actually make it into the `.vbox` file. Most likely a typo prevented me from doing this before. The commands were:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage setextradata Testinstall "VboxInternal/Devices/piix4ide/0/Config/PrimaryMaster/ModelNumber" "INTEL SSD1602CW"

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage setextradata Testinstall "VboxInternal/Devices/piix4ide/0/Config/PrimaryMaster/FirmwareRevision" "1602CW.1.3"

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage setextradata Testinstall "VboxInternal/Devices/piix4ide/0/Config/PrimaryMaster/SerialNumber" "1602CW1800200926"
```

However, the output of `hdparm -I /dev/sda` still says the disk is of model "VBOX HARDDISK". In other words, the issue remains the same.

Comment: Just some idead: did you reboot the virtual machine? (Just in case it was somehow cached...). Please add the version of Virtualbox, guest kernel and check materially inside the hdd description file (in the folder with the hdd image the file `*.vbox` ) if your commands modify something. Good luck.

Comment: @Hastur yes-ish. The machine was off while I ran the vboxmanage commands. I then proceeded to boot the virtual machine and check the disk. Additional versian data edited into the question.

Comment: Go into SL and do the mount command with no arguments, this should show you (a version of) the /etc/mtab file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you misunderstood the meaning of the `setextradata/getextradata` option. According to [the VBox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idm5419),

> These commands let you attach and retrieve string data to a virtual machine or to a VirtualBox configuration (by specifying global instead of a virtual machine name).

The use case presented is the following:

```
# VBoxManage setextradata Fedora5 installdate 2006.01.01
# VBoxManage getextradata Fedora5 installdate
    VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 5.1.6
    (C) 2005-2016 Oracle Corporation
    All rights reserved.

    Value: 2006.01.01
```

Here `installdate` is a keyword associated with the following string, `2006.0.1.01`; invoking the keyword returns the associated string. In other words, `setextradata/getextradata` is a way of `burning` into the VM some kind of data whose retrieval may be helpful in the future.

It has nothing to do with *emulat[ing] a "real" harddrive*. AFAIK, there is no such option in VBox; if you think otherwise, can you please provide some references?

From what you write, the commands you mention were taken  from  someone who attached to his VM some labels detailing the properties of the HDD on which the VM was running. Following the syntax given by the manual, the strings *"ISD000081", "83CJ0015", "INTEL SSD1602CW"* were assigned to a VM called *TestInstall*, under the (long) keywords represented by the file paths. **If** you have a VM called TestInstall, then these strings will be available by querying the VM with the commands given above, for instance

```
vboxmanage getextradata "Testinstall" "VBoxInternal/Devices/piix4ide/0/Config/PrimaryMaster/FirmwareRevision"
```

should return the string

```
 "ISD000081"
```

You may try this to  check whether what I told you is correct, or you may simply open the *xml* file which describes the VM generally called *TestInstall.vbox*, and you will find a new line like this,

```
<ExtraDataItem name="keyword" value="character_string"/>
```

which again shows what the commmands *setextradata/getextradata* are used for.

Comment: In general you would be right, but VboxInternal key are also read by VirtualBox's internal routines to set up the virtual hardware. As such, they *do* affect the results of internal commands such as `hdparm`.

Answer (score -1):

## Scenario

I believe that you have some software on the VM that checks it is running on a specific hard disk, and does so by reading its make and model. So, the software will run on the real machine but will refuse to do so on the virtualized machine.

Equivalently, you do *not* want the software to realize it is running on a virtual machine, and the software checks for telltales such as the hard disk having a factory brand of "VBOX".

**If this scenario is correct**, then your approach is also correct - have VirtualBox report the same information of the real machine. This is done using a special branch of the ExtraData property tree.

**If it is not correct**, and you want to emulate some other, *possibly* even physical property of the hard disk (seek times, latency, or something else), then @MariusMatutiae's answer is the correct one - what you're doing is not the way to do it, and it will simply not work.

## It works!

You are probably using the incorrect VBoxManage syntax, or maybe are referring to the wrong controller (e.g. you are not using PIIX4 but, say, AHCI). You can still set PIIX4 extradata even when using AHCI or PIIX3, except that of course they won't affect the machine.

I've just tried on one of my VMs, which uses AHCI hard disk (all on one line):

```
D:\Programmi\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage setextradata
    "Aladdin-Clone" "VBoxInternal/Devices/ahci/0/Config/Port0/ModelNumber" 
    "HITACHI HTD723216L9SA61"
```

and I did obtain (I only changed the model number, but have no reason to believe the other two keys wouldn't work)

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       HITACHI HTD723216L9SA61
        Serial Number:      VB35affeb2-744b8198
        Firmware Revision:  1.0
Standards:
        Used: ATA/ATAPI-6 published, ANSI INCITS 361-2002
        Supported: 6 5 4
```

## Update

There is a complete Python script on github, "[antivmdetection](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nsmfoo/antivmdetection/master/antivmdetect.py)", that allows customizing a VirtualBox machine so that it closely resembles another. You can run the script on a machine to save the data and it will generate a script to modify a VM... or you can look at the source code and lift the commands from there. **Notice that there is more than one command to set the drive make and model depending on the controller**.

Comment: You are equivocating, just like @Jarmund: all you are doing, and the same applies to the python script you referenced, is to **change the labels** of the VM, you are **not** simulating anything.  The OP states: *I now need to emulate a "real" harddrive*, that's a whole different matter.

Comment: I took "simulating a real hard disk" to mean "have something in  the guest VM believe It is running on a specific hard disk". The hard disk is of course already simulated, that's what VirtualBox is about.

Comment: Google returns: *emulate:...:(COMPUTING)
reproduce the function or action of (a different computer, software system, etc.).*

Comment: Thanks, @MariusMatutiae . I have updated my answer to more clearly reflect my understanding of the problem. It is entirely possible that I'm mistaken and will end up retracting both my downvote and my answer. Let's see what the OP says.